# Como preencher toda a tela no modo "landscape" Table Layout?

Tags: java, android, landscape, tablelayout

Eu estou usando um "TableLayout" em meu aplicativo. Este é meu código XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:scrollbars="none">

<include
    android:id="@id/action_bar"
    layout="@layout/actionbar_toolbar" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/action_bar">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

O quadro é preenchido dinamicamente com código:

```
TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
TextView txt_plazo = new TextView(this);
txt_plazo.setText(" Plazo ");
txt_plazo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
txt_plazo.setTextSize(16);
txt_plazo.setMinimumHeight(0);
txt_plazo.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
txt_plazo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tbrow.addView(txt_plazo);

TextView txt_saldoInicial = new TextView(this);
txt_saldoInicial.setText(" Saldo Inicial");
txt_saldoInicial.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
txt_saldoInicial.setTextSize(16);
txt_saldoInicial.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
txt_saldoInicial.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tbrow.addView(txt_saldoInicial);

TextView txt_parcialidades = new TextView(this);
txt_parcialidades.setText(" Parcialidades ");
txt_parcialidades.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
txt_parcialidades.setTextSize(16);
txt_parcialidades.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
txt_parcialidades.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tbrow.addView(txt_parcialidades);

TextView txt_interes = new TextView(this);
txt_interes.setText(" Interés ");
txt_interes.setTextSize(16);
txt_interes.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
txt_interes.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
txt_interes.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tbrow.addView(txt_interes);

TextView txt_total = new TextView(this);
txt_total.setText(" Abono Capital");
txt_total.setTextSize(16);
txt_total.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
txt_total.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
txt_total.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tbrow.addView(txt_total);

table.addView(tbrow);
```

Etc ...

Tudo funciona bem, mas eu estou tentando ver a tabela no modo "landscape", o problema é que a tabela não preencher toda a tela.

[image: landscape]

Eu já tentei: `android: stretchColumns = "*"`, mas ele só funciona em telas pequenas.

[image: telas pequenas]

Já tentei de tudo, mas nada funciona. Enquanto apenas ver o modo "landscape" em telas pequenas.

Comment: Tenta colocar `android:layout_width="math_parent"` em `HorizontalScrollView` e `ScrollView`, e `android:layout_weight="1"` no `TabLayout`.

Comment: Ya intenté usar "match_parent" es la respuesta que veo siempre, pero no funciona. Y android:layout_weight="1" no funciona no TableLayout.